# Event calendar help - creating view of event with all registered users in a block

Tags: datetime

I am new to Drupal so I encounter this problem. I've installed Event Callendar. Using tutorials found all over the web I made a signup content type and displaying list of registered users for each event using Eva reference.

I would like to make a block of latest event and registered users in the front page. The problem is that my list of registered users take context filter from node URL (where event content is displayed).

How can I put all of this in a single block and set context filter of users list to URL of the event?

This is very confusing. I am trying to do it for the last two days with no luck ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a block and output your view with PHP, that way you can control which argument to pass:

```
<?php
  print views_embed_view('your_view_name', 'display_id', $your_argument);
?>
```

You can get `'your_view_name'` and `'display_id'`from the view's edit page:

- `'your_view_name'` from the URL, something like `admin/structure/views/view/your_view_name`
- `'display_id'` on the right side under "Other" > "Machine Name". It's usually something simple like `'block_1'`, or if you have a single display, try `'default'`.

Also remember to set the text format to PHP code.

Comment: So if I am getting this right I can paste this in template of a view to render another one with argument? 'your_view_name' and  'display_id' comes form the view I want to show right?